# What is the Features specific data in a Features module's .info file

Tags: 7, features

I'm not sure if this is a Features module question or simply a module construction question.

I have a module which was constructed with Features, which I have never used before. In the `.info` file of the module there are a lot of lines that read similar to `features[something][] = something`.

What is this and where is it used in the module?

Comment: Hi :) Please try to keep to one question per question. The second part of this was actually quite a good question - I'd suggest posting it as a standalone question.

Comment: Thanks, I did here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/83104/inc-files-in-features-how-are-they-being-included

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the documentation is sparse (still!?) https://drupal.org/node/1720098

The entries in your `.info` file tell Features that that item of your configuration is controlled by Features and not say Drupal core. You'll see stuff like `ctools` or `views` in there. In the main `features.inc` file the features info hook will require those API dependancies.

Based upon other lines in the info file such as:

```
features[ctools][] = strongarm:strongarm:1
features[ctools][] = views:views_default:3.0
features[user_permission][] = create features_test content
features[views_view][] = features_test
```

These lines would say, features uses Strongarm to read/write configuration of variables, and Ctools integration. Then there is some view `features_test` and some user permission exported `create features_test content`.

From the documentation page i linked these `.info` configuration values then:

> They are called during hook_module_enable/disable to fire the right
>   stuff in the right places.

By Features itself. The info file contents tells Features what its managing. The `.inc` files include the dynamic configuration values needed per `.info` item entry (usually in terms of plain Drupal hook_info configuration definitions that'd you basically be making in code anyways).

I recommend reading the Features API and Readme:

http://drupalcode.org/project/features.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/API.txt

http://drupalcode.org/project/features.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/README.txt

Comment: Thank for the answer and the links! I will read through them and hopfully that will answer all of my questions.