# .inc files in Features - how are they being included?

Tags: 7, features

Regarding the features module: I am working with a module which was created by features. I see a lot of .inc files in the module, but see very few actually included. Does this make any sense? I know that they are all being used and are creating fields etc.

Comment: Creating fields only needs to happen once, that would probably explain why you don't see the files included - they've already been included the one time they were needed

Comment: Oh, and how does features know about these files to include them once?

Comment: Looks like the work is done in [`features_include()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!features!features.module/function/features_include/7) and [`features_include_defaults()`](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/features_include_defaults/7), at the root of it it seems to be a simple file naming convention

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most include files exported by features are included on-demand by the modules that define that type of component.  For instance, `example.views_default.inc` is included by the views module when loading default views.  This is a common pattern in Drupal, not something that is specific to Features.